# upload files to specific user

Tags: file, upload, drupal-7

I want to let admin upload files (PDF files) to a separate user (client), such as bill, information and documentation.

I think to Add new content type with some fields, like *file* field, but I don't know how to add *users* list, so admin can choose file to upload and corresponding user.

After I finish this step, how can I display these files to user when login?

Answer (score 2):

To reference the user, you could install the entity reference module.
http://drupal.org/project/entityreference
You can use that to add a field that will reference users.

As far as listing files for the user, you can use Views to make a list of your new content type, and filter it by the user who is logged in.

To elaborate more, Install the Views module, and make a new View, with a content-type filter for your new type, and a contextual filter for current User, and then add a Field for the file field, and configure the field however you would like the file to be displayed to the user.
Depending on what you want, you could also set that view as the frontpage of your site, so that  people will see it when they log in.

To filter by current user, when you add the Contextual Filter, in the "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL" section, select "Provide Default Value" and then select the type "User ID from logged in user"

Comment: +1 if it's just a user reference though you should use the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references), it's more stable.

Comment: great, but please give me some more details about how to display uploaded files to user>

Comment: @Clive Yeah, both will work. One of the first bullet points on the References module page says that it will probably be deprecated soon though.

Comment: @OsamaKobaitari I added a bit more of a description for the Views.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Fair point I take that back, it's tricky to pick between a stable module that will be deprecated as soon as it's successor comes out of beta, and the successor module itself. For longevity you're right though, Entity Reference probably would be a better choice.

Comment: @Clive Yeah, it is tough to choose.

Comment: #loganfsmyth actually, still not clear how to make a file related to one user filtered by user_id field specified in my content type.  When I add contextual filters, there is no field to tell filter about current user.

Comment: @OsamaKobaitari Right, I forgot it's kind of hard to find. Updated my answer.